# SQL query to retrieve a group records

Tags: sql

I'm not sure how to describe this, but I'm trying to retrieve all the records that have a common index and have a specific value in a separate field...

Table: Response

```
responseID     objective   
===============================
AAA            Posted          
AAA            Aligned      
AAB            Aligned
AAB            Null
AAC            Posted
AAC            Null
```

Based on the value "Posted" in the objective field, the query would return the following from the table response:

```
responseID     objective   
===============================
AAA            Posted          
AAA            Aligned      
AAC            Posted
AAC            Null
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Especially help with the vocabulary terms as I'm just beginning with queries.

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to get rows for any keys in `responseId` for which there is a value 'Posted' in the column `objective`.  The SQL term for that is "exists" - do any rows exist in this query?

This should work just fine:

```
DECLARE VARCHAR(50) @objective = 'Posted';

select data1.*
from data data1
where exists 
(
  select 1
  from data data2
  where data2.responseid = data1.responseid 
    and data2.objective = @objective
);
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle showing that it works in MS SQL Server 2012](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d39fb/6/6)

Answer (score 1):

```
select r.responseid, r.objective
  from response r
  join (select responseid from response where objective = 'Posted') v
    on r.responseid = v.responseid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists` operator to get the `Response` which has objective `'Posted'`.

```
SELECT responseID, objective 
FROM Response a
WHERE exists (select 1 from Response b where a.responseid = b.responseid
and b.objective = 'Posted')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with `exists` -- that is, get all responses where one of the objectives is `Posted`:

```
select r.*
from response r
where exists (select 1
              from response r2
              where r2.responseid = r.responseid and r2.objective = 'Posted'
             );
```